# duplicate Combobox is adding in cells in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using dynamic combo box in datatgridview and its populating correctly. 
But when i tried to add new row for the datagridview,by clicking a button **Add New Row**,this combo box is repeating in cells.
If i click once , one combo box will be added in cell1,second click to add one more row,two combo box is added in cells.
How can i add new row in datagridview without repeating this combo box in cells?
My code is as follows:

```
 private void btnRMAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //add new row
            dgItemGroup.Rows.Add();
            fnInsertColumnsCombo();
        }

 private void fnInsertColumnsCombo()
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combo1.Name = "GroupName";
            combo1.HeaderText = "GroupName";
            string sqlStr = "SELECT GroupID,GroupName FROM tblITEMGROUP ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            combo1.DataSource = dt;
            combo1.DisplayMember = "GroupName";
            combo1.ValueMember = "GroupID";
            combo1.AutoComplete = true;
            combo1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            dgItemGroup.Columns.Insert(0, combo1);
            dgItemGroup.Columns[0].Width = 250;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method fnInsertColumnsCombo, you are adding a new column to the grid each time you add a new row. This method is called each time you add a new row. Maybe you want to add a column in the "init" phase and then populate the data after adding the new row.